# Telerik RadTimeline respond to mouse clicks

Tags: silverlight, telerik

Is there any way to know if the user has clicked on an item in RadTimeline? I would like to handle the click and do something with the selected timeline item, but my searching hasn't revealed any way to handle this. I can capture the mouse click on MouseLeftButtonDown event, but I don't see a way to tell which item was hit, if any.

Comment: According to Telerik, this feature is not supported, but will be available for Q1 2012 SP1 or Q2 2012 release. I have since found a workaround that does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Telerik, this feature is not supported, but will be available for Q1 2012 SP1 or Q2 2012 release.

However, after researching it, I found a workaround that seems to work. If you override the TimelineItemTemplate with a DataTemplate that has a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event on it, then you can use the DataContext of the sender to get the bound data.

XAML:

```
<telerik:RadTimeline x:Name="MatchTimeline" Height="250" PeriodStart="3/1/2012" PeriodEnd="3/30/2012">
<telerik:RadTimeline.Intervals>
    <telerik:DayInterval/>
    <telerik:HourInterval/>
</telerik:RadTimeline.Intervals>
<telerik:RadTimeline.TimelineItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Height="14">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Height="10" Fill="Blue" MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:RadTimeline.TimelineItemTemplate>
```

Code:

```
private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MyTimelineItem item = (MyTimelineItem)(((Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataItemBase)(((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(sender)).DataContext)).DataItem);
    item.IWasHere();
}
```